# Proxy reversing SSL server in Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I am struggling with proxy reversing an SSL server in Apache.
Right now I have many websites under many subdomains in one domain.
For example:

```
gitlab.mydomain.com
nextcloud.mydomain.com
plex.mydomain.com
```

All the websites use Letsencrypt certificates so they are HTTPS enabled.

The thing is, that so far no server running at my localhost was HTTPS. For example Plex is running as a standalone HTTP server on my localhost which I simply proxy reverse using Apache and in the internet it is secured with Letsencrypt.

Now I need to proxy reverse an already secured HTTP server. Namely Jenkins - it is running with Letsencrypt on my localhost for various reasons. I should also mention that the certificate used to encrypt it on localhost is the same as the certificate I use in Apache.

So my Jenkins is running on port 8443 and my Apache configuration for Jenkins is the following:

```
# Just to redirect HTTP to HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName jenkins.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias www.jenkins.mydomain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost *:443>
    ServerName jenkins.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias https://jenkins.mydomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Proxy https://localhost:8443/jenkins*>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8443/jenkins nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8443/jenkins
    ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://jenkins.mydomain.com/jenkins
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule   "^/$"  "/jenkins/"  [R]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  path/to/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/privkey.pem
</Virtualhost>
```

However, with this configuration I get an **error 502 (Proxy Error)**:

*The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /jenkins/.
Reason: Error reading from remote server*

Answer (score 0):

The 502 you're getting is because Apache isn't receiving a response from `http://localhost:8443/jenkins`. This is the first issue that needs to be resolved before anything else can work. Ensure that you are able to access Jenkins by utilizing `cURL`.

For example: `curl http://localhost:8443/jenkins` if no response then try `curl https://localhost:8443/jenkins` if no response there, then I'd take a look and see if Jenkins is configured properly.

There are a couple things I did notice that should be updated in your Virtual Host configuration.

1. `ServerAlias https://jenkins.mydomain.com` should be `ServerAlias www.jenkins.mydomain.com` as `https://` should not be included in a `ServerAlias` directive, plus you may want to be able to get to the site using `https://www.jenkins.mydomain.com` since that's in the non-https directive. You also most likely will want to include a rewrite in your https virtual host that rewrites `www.jenkins.mydomain.com` to `jenkins.mydomain.com`.
2. You probably don't need the second `ProxyPassReverse` directive.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but the Jenkins runs just fine on localhost (`https://localhost:8443/jenkins`) and this configuration worked properly when the jenkins was running HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: Okay, but you're still receiving the 502?

Comment: Only when I access it via the Apache at jenkins.mydomain.com. Based on which I suppose only the proxy reverse is wrong. But to be honest, configuring Apache is not my forte.

Comment: Okay. let me test some stuff really quick and see about this.

Comment: Have you been following this tutorial: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

Comment: No, I used some configurations from other websites I am running as a template, but as I am looking at it, it seems to be very close to what I have right now. But even when I try to apply some changes according to the website you've posted, I still can't get it working.

Comment: Have you had any luck since yesterday? Did the behavior change when you applied any of those changes?

Comment: I have tried some parts of the configuration the wiki provides, but with no luck. Either I get 502, or Internal Server Error.